# Compute the difference between two days.

Tags: code-golf, date

Another date-manipulating problem :P

### Task

> Write a program or a function that calculates the difference between two dates given by a user.

### Input & Output

Similar to [the previous one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2878/1477), inputs are two `YYYYMMDD`s, separated by a space , a comma `,`, or a minus sign `-`.

Example of input values:

```
20100101-20010911
20110620-20121223
19000101 20101010
33330101,19960229
00010101 99991231
```

Output is an integer, which is difference between two dates, in days.

For example, input `20110101-20100101` yields `365`, and `33320229 17000101` yields `596124`.

You may test results <del>[at here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=difference+between+1700%2F01%2F01+and+3332%2F02%2F29%2C+in+days)</del> [at here](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/duration.html). (See rintaun's comments below.) If two dates are same, the program should returns `0`, if the date is valid (see **Score**).

### Restriction

Of course, you **must** not use **any** kinds of function/class/... which are related to timestamp or date, and you should use [Gregorian calender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar).

### Score

If your code doesn't keep the restriction, then `score = -∞`.

Default `bonus` is 1.

- If your code works regardless of order of inputs (for example, `20100101,20110101` returns `365` or `-365`), `bonus+=1`.
- If your code can handle [year 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_0), `bonus+=0.5`.
- If your code recognizes invalid month(between 1~12)/date(between 1~31), like `20109901` or `34720132`, and prints `E` (& terminates the program or returns something like `0`), `bonus+=1`.
- Regardless of above rule, if your code recognizes invalid dates, like `20100230`, `20100229`, or `20111131`, and prints `E` (& terminates the program or returns something like `0`), `bonus+=1`.
- Regardless of above two rules, if your code recognizes invalid input string, like `20100101|20100202` or `2010010120100202`, and prints `E` (& terminates the program or returns something like `0`), `bonus+=1`.

`score = floor(-4.2*code.length/bonus)`. Code with highest score wins. If two top codes have same score, then codes with highest bonus wins. If two top codes have both same score and bonus, then codes with highest votes wins.

(Due: When there's more than 5 codes which has more than (or equal) `+1` votes.)

Comment: Is 20030229 considered an invalid date by the third bonus?

Comment: @rintaun Yes. It's invalid, unlike `20040229`. :P

Comment: Does WolframAlpha actually return the correct result? I'm getting conflicting answers from [it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convert+1996%2F02%2F27+to+2000%2F03%2F01+to+days) and [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=02&d1=27&y1=1996&m2=03&d2=01&y2=2000). My program, which I believe is working correctly (at least in that instance :P), agrees with the latter.

Comment: @rintaun I think Wolfram|Alpha was wrong, since `365*4 + 2 + 2` = 1464. Thanks for the information!

Comment: It should be noted that even with timeanddate.com, there are some problems: it only accepts years 1-3999, and it auto-adjusts for the 11-day discrepancy between the Julian and Gregorian calendars for dates prior to Sept. 3, 1752 (so 17520903 through 17520914 are not valid dates). Keep this in mind when testing results.

Comment: Mathematica 8 can call wolfram alpha from a notebook... Is this acceptable?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "handle year 0" under the Gregorian calendar? Are we supposed to treat it as 1 BC?

Comment: Also, are we supposed to account for the jump between Julian and Gregorian? (i.e. subtract 11 days) Or can we ignore it? This isn't clear in the question.

Comment: @migimaru Handle year 0 as leap year (like year 2000). And you should ignore the jump before Julian and Gregorian, since only the Gregorian calender is used (...and you should use Gregorian calender.)

Comment: @JiminP Okay, though it's confusing because you use the example `33320229 17000101` = `596124`. That's only true if the jump is accounted for, otherwise it should be `596135` when only using the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: @migimaru ...I think I need a good date calculator...

Comment: It sounds like you intend people to calculate using the [proleptic gregorian calendar](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=proleptic+gregorian+calendar).

Comment: You can use `perl6 -e 'say [-] @*ARGS.map: {Date.new(|+«%(m/$<year>=(\d**4)$<month>=(\d**2)$<day>=(\d**2)/))}' 33320229 17000101` (596134) to test ( [Perl 6 uses the proleptic gregorian calendar](http://design.perl6.org/S32/Temporal.html). )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Perl 5.14, score = -162

<strike>-163</strike> <strike>-181</strike> <strike>-196</strike> <strike>-214</strike> <strike>-167</strike> <strike>-213</strike> <strike>-234</strike>

- code.length = 211: 208 source characters + 3 for running perl with the `-p` option
- bonus = 5.5: default, order, year 0, never-valid month/day, invalid date, wholly-invalid input

#### Code

```
$_=eval(join'-',map{($y,$m,$d)=/(....)(..)(..)/;die"E\n"if!($m*$d)||$m>12||$d>30+($m&1^$m>7)-($m==2)*(2-!($y=~s/00$//r%4));$y-=($m<3)-400;$d+int(($m+9)%12*30.6+.4)+int(365.2425*$y)}/^(\d{8})[ ,-](\d{8})$/)//E
```

Calculates a modified Julian day number for each date (ignoring the epoch-related adjustments to save code length) and subtracts the two. (ref. ["Julian Day" at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Converting_Gregorian_calendar_date_to_Julian_Day_Number)).

- requires perl 5.14+ for the `/r` option on the substitutions
- month-length calculation to get the invalid date bonus: the `30+($m&1^$m>7)` part gives the length of any month but February; the rest adjusts for February in an ordinary or leap year

#### Assumptions

- "use Gregorian calendar" means the proleptic Gregorian calendar for dates before whichever Julian to Gregorian transition we're using.  That is, don't subtract 11 days for intervals that cross, for example, the 3 Sep 1752 - 14 Sep 1752 British transition.
- "handle year 0" means, for example, `00000101-00010101` should give 366, as 0 is an integral multiple of 400, and so year 0 is a leap year.

Comment: With the changes you made, it seems like your program now accepts invalid months and days, like `20111300-20119999` returns `2717`.

Comment: @migimaru: I have indeed optimized out the correctness. Darn. I'll edit and maybe come back to it.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, Score: -539.1

- 706 characters
- All bonus items; bonus = 5.5

### Code

```
<?php $a='(\d{4})(0[0-9]|1[0-2])([0-2][0-9]|3[01])';@$p=preg_match;if(!$p('/^(\d{8})[- ,](\d{8})$/',fgets(STDIN),$z))@die(E);unset($z[0]);sort($z);foreach($z AS$x){if(!$p('/(\d{4})(0[0-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/',$x,$w))die(E);$n[]=$w;}$m=array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);$r=0;$b=$n[0][1];$c=$n[0][2];$d=$n[0][3];$e=$n[1][1];$f=$n[1][2];$g=$n[1][3];@$t=str_pad;if((($b.$e==229)&&(!(!($b%4)+!($b%100)-!($b%400))))||($c>12))die(E);for($z=$b.$c.$d;;$s=$d,$r++){if($z==$e.$f.$g)break;if($z>$e.$f.$g)@die(E);if(@$s==$d)$d++;if((($c!=2)&&($d>$m[$c-1]))||(($c==2)&&($d>($m[$c-1]+!($b%4)-!($b%100)+!($b%400))))){$c++;$d=1;}if($c>12){$b++;$c=1;}$z=$b.$t($c,2,0,0).$t($d,2,0,0);}echo($r>0)?--$r:0;
```

#### Ungolfed

```
<?php
$a='(\d{4})(0[0-9]|1[0-2])([0-2][0-9]|3[01])';
@$p=preg_match;
if(!$p('/^(\d{8})[- ,](\d{8})$/',fgets(STDIN),$z)) @die(E);
unset($z[0]);
sort($z);
foreach($z AS $x)
{
        if (!$p('/(\d{4})(0[0-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/',$x,$w)) die(E);
        $n[]=$w;
}
$m=array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);
$r=0;
$b=$n[0][1];
$c=$n[0][2];
$d=$n[0][3];
$e=$n[1][1];
$f=$n[1][2];
$g=$n[1][3];
@$t=str_pad;
if ((($b.$e==229)&&(!(!($b%4)+!($b%100)-!($b%400))))||($c>12)) die(E);
for ($z=$b.$c.$d;;$s=$d,$r++)
{
        if ($z==$e.$f.$g)break;
        if ($z>$e.$f.$g)@die(E);
        if (@$s==$d)$d++;
        if ((($c!=2)&&($d>$m[$c-1]))||(($c==2)&&($d>($m[$c-1]+!($b%4)-!($b%100)+!($b%400)))))
        {
                $c++;
                $d=1;
        }
        if ($c>12)
        {
                $b++;
                $c=1;
        }
        $z=$b.$t($c,2,0,0).$t($d,2,0,0);
}
echo($r>0)?--$r:0;
```

### Note

Calculates the number of days by iterating through each valid date between the two provided. It's pretty slow on larger ranges. I'm sure this isn't the best way to solve this, but I got impatient, and this is what I ended up with. :)

Also, I know the "ungolfed" code still isn't very readable, but rewriting it completely would require too much effort.

Answer (score 2):

### Python, Score: -478

- characters: 455
- bonus: reverse dates, invalid day/month, invalid date

solution:

```
import re
a=re.split('[-, ]',raw_input())
def c(x):return x[0]
def f(x,y=3):return(1if x%400==0 or x%100!=0and x%4==0 else 0)if y>2 else 0
t=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
[q,w,e],[i,o,p]=sorted([map(int,[a[x][:4],a[x][4:6],a[x][6:]])for x in[0,1]],key=c)
print sum(map(f,range(q,i)))+(i-q)*365+p+sum(t[:o-1])-e-sum(t[:w-1])+f(i,o)-f(q,w)if 0<w<13and 0<e<32and 0<o<13and 0<p<32and(e<=t[w-1]or(f(q)and e==29))and(p<=t[o-1]or(f(i)and p==29))else 'E'
```

I don't have "ungolfed" version as this is how I wrote it. I didn't test it properly so if you find a bug - please comment.

edit: hopefully fixed a bug pointed out in a comments and added unpacking in form of [a,b],[c,d]=[[1,2],[3,4]

Comment: Sorry, but when I tested with Python 2.7 Shell, invalid inputs like '20000001,20010101' doesn't print `E`. (FYI, `0>-1>12`, `0>6>12`, `0>13>12` returns `False`.)

Comment: Thanks. I'm quite new to python. Writing this script I learned that python does this `x<y<z` comparison or there is a `x if y else z`. Tried to fix it.

Comment: @rpInt: for golfing, there is also the `[x,z][y]` which is shorter than `x if y else z`, though it doesn't always work since unlike the if-expression it's not lazy.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby 1.9, Score: -175 <strike>-186</strike> <strike>-191</strike> <strike>-199</strike>

- Code length: 229 <strike>243</strike> <strike>250</strike> <strike>260</strike> characters
- Bonus: 5.5 (default, order, year 0, invalid month/day, invalid date, invalid input)

The code accepts input through stdin.

```
h=->n{n/4-n/100+n/400+1}
u,v=gets.split(/[ ,-]/).map{|s|s=~/^\d{8}$/?(d,e,f=[s[0,4],s[4,2],s[6,2]].map &:to_i;x=[0,y=31,28+h[d]-z=h[d-1]]+[y,30,y,30,y]*2
(!x[e]||e*f<1||f>x[e])?0:d*365+z+eval(x[0,e]*?+)+f):0}
puts (v*u>0)?u-v :?E
```

Notes:

- h returns the number of leap years up until that year (including year 0 for the bonus).
- The regex handles the invalid input bonus.
- The `(!x[e]||e*f<1||f>x[e])` condition handles the invalid month/day/date bonuses.
- The result is displayed as the first date minus the second date, so if the second date is later it will output as a negative number.
- Does not adjust for the change between Julian and Gregorian calendars, so `33320229 17000101` results in `596134`.

Comment: Thanks for error-checking my solution and for pushing me to keep improving. I particularly like your February-length calculation here.

Comment: @DCharness Thanks for pushing me as well. I realized there was plenty of room for improvement in my original submission.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, score: -516

chars : <strike>685</strike> 676

bonus : 5.5

```
<? $z='/((\d{1,4})(\d\d)(\d\d))[- ,]((\d{1,4})(\d\d)(\d\d))/';if(!preg_match($z,$argv[1],$m))die('E');$s=1;if($m[1]>$m[5]){if(!preg_match($z,"$m[5] $m[1]",$m))die('E');$s=-1;}$b=array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);list($x,$v,$c,$d,$e,$w,$f,$g,$h)=$m;if($d>12||1>$d||$g>12||1>$g||1>$e||1>$h||($e>$b[$d-1]&&!($d==2&&$e<30&&$c%4==0))||($h>$b[$g-1]&&!($g==2&&$h<30&&$f%4==0)))die('E');$z='array_slice';$y='array_sum';$x=$d!=$g||$e>$h;$r=$x?$b[$d-1]+$h-$e:$h-$e;$d+=$x;if($d>12){$c++;$d=1;}$r+=$d>$g?$y($z($b,$d-1,13-$d))+$y($z($b,0,$g-1)):($d!=$g?$y($z($b,$d-1,$g-$d)):0);$r+=($f-$c-($d>$g))*365;for($i=$c;$i<=$f;$i++)if($i%4==0&&$i.'0229'>$v&&$i.'0229'<$w)$r++;echo $s*$r;
```

Comment: PHP code needs the `<?` at the beginning to run, otherwise it just prints out the code.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 294 bytes, ~-353 score, +3.5 bonus

```powershell
function J($s){if($s.length-ne8){"E";exit};iex ('$Y_0,4));$M_4,2));$D_6,2))'-replace'_','=[int]($s.substring(');$B=($M-14)/12;if($m-notin1..12){'E';exit};$A=$Y+4800;($J=1461*($A+$B)/4+367*($M-2-12*$B)/12-(3*(($A+$B+100)/100))/4+$D-32075)};[math]::truncate((J("$($args[0])"))-(J("$($args[1])")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/RioMwEEV/pUggiRqbxKwtDT60tC9CP6CIiFtSDdhYNGUL0m93k919WAZmDpfLvcxj@FLj1Km@X5bb01ytHsyqQGDCs765k/TKtLYjRm3xHJwCqV7avqVWrxWC4FLTWGAswbkWMfdwrDMPkIzq0TdXBWsYw7zUxlY@bXp@TnbUpkXQmQ85AmfCBF4zLn3dnZjBasOShHE8wxP8qwP7HFwisaVUIlDkTGQsRGAfgQNeiyjNNqEP4oTx0EuME5SG6NcRMUqd5Jb3giNJOd184Lcs743tqt3Oju7vxiqEChQABJqxnUpa4QBj8l9iPxJeloVTxqgbD9TDNw)

It uses Julian Date to calculate difference between to `YYYYMMDD` dates.

**Explanation**

- At first, to avoid redundant code, it's better to use a function. So we declare a function named `J` which calculates the julian date of a given date in `YYYYMMDD` format, and takes the parameter as `$s`.
- Next, we need to check for invalid string. If the given string length is not 8 (`YYYYMMDD` length is 8), then output `E` and exit.
- Parse the string. We used substrings for that. First 4 characters are the year (`$Y`), next 2 are the month (`$M`), and next 2 are the day (`$D`). To get a substring, we use .NET `.substring()` method for that, and cast it to type `[int]`. But its a huge part of code, and to golf it we replace `=[int]($s.substring(` with `_` and build a string `$Y_0,4));$M_4,2));$D_6,2))` and while in the code replace `_` with `=[int]($s.substring(` again and evaluate the expression using `iex` (Which is an alias of `Invoke-Expression`).
- Another check for month validity. `1..12` is the array of numbers between `1` to `12`, if `$M` (month number) is not in the `1..12` array, we output `E` and exit.
- Then the main logic goes. We calculate the Julian date. I found the algorithm [here](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetimentmath.php)
- End the function.
- We compute date difference after that. `$args` is an automatic array in Powershell which contains the parameters provided to the script (Not the function). We cast 0 and 1 index to string (`$()` operator is sub-expression operator, which evaluates a string as code inside a double-quoted string, and then surround double quotes to cast to string), pass each to `J` function and subtract the returned integer Julian dates.
- At last, truncate the result using .NET `[math]::truncate()` method.

**Bonus**

- Initial bonus, so bonus +1
- The code will work if the first date is smaller than second one (i.e. `20100101 20110101`), so bonus +1
- Cannot handle year 0, so bonus +0
- Can handle invalid month, but not invalid Day, so bonus +0.5
- Cannot determine invalid dates, so bonus +0
- Can handle invalid strings in parameters, so bonus +1

Total: `1+1+0+0.5+0+1=3.5`

**Total score**

- Code length: 294 bytes
- Total bonus: +3.5

$$
floor(-4.2*294/3.5) = -353
$$