# Which weekday was it?

Tags: code-golf, date

This challenge, I hope, is simple to understand. Given a date-string (given in any format you prefer, **so long as it has 4 digits of year and 2 digits of day and month**), calculate the weekday for the particular date-string. You must output 7 different values, corresponding to the weekday you have calculated.

It's okay if your program only theoretically (given enough time and memory) prints the correct weekday, as long as it can calculate for years between 2000 and 2002.

If you're using a built-in, consider adding a non-built-in approach as well. Built-in solutions won't be considered for being accepted.

Make sure to account for leap years!

### Test cases

Input format is `DD/MM/YYYY`, output is one of `Su, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa` (both can be adjusted for your choice)

```
Input -> Output
12/11/2001 -> Mo
29/02/2000 -> Tu
04/07/2002 -> Th
11/08/2000 -> Fr
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins!

**EDIT**:
When I said "No built-ins", I meant that *built-ins that automatically calculate the weekday for a particular date* were *discouraged*, not prohibited. If the built-in aids in finding the weekday, no problem, but if it directly calculates the weekday then I *discourage* it.

Comment: Yeah, you can, so long as you mention which `int` it is for each day.

Comment: Can we take year, month, and day as numeric arguments, or does it have to be a string?

Comment: You can do that too, but specify which argument stands for which.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether we have to support dates outside the range 2000-2002? With the current wording, I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Can we take input as a builtin date object?

Comment: @Arnauld my reading: it must theoretically be able to do so, but it's OK if memory constraints make this impossible; e.g. if you stack overflow for inputs 2003 and onward, its OK so long the algorithm for getting the weekday would have been correct given infinite memory or something.

Comment: "any format you prefer" — does that include `7|1⎕DT⊂YYYY MM DD`?

Comment: No @Arnauld, you dont need to

Comment: And @Steffan, yes

Comment: and yes @Adám, that too

Comment: Is a valid solution just `eval` or the equivalent in any language, just with all the code as part of the input? Or is that blocked by the 'no built-ins' requirement?

Comment: If the built-in doesn't calculate the weekday, its ok.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "built-ins"? Does it only cover things to solve the entire problem, like Mathematica's `DayName` or does it include any type of date-handling capability? Isn't `+` a built-in?

Comment: Does the built-in calculate weekdays? If it does, I discourage it.

Comment: I'm VTCing this since the built-in ban is particularly subjective here. I'd recommend just getting rid of it, and maybe _encouraging_ not using built-ins.

Comment: @py3programmer How about a built-in that computes a date serial number (number of days since an epoch)? Such a number has the inherent property which is its remainder when divided by seven, and that's the weekday. Forbidden or not? Also, you allow built-in date objects, but they might well have an accessible day-of-week property. Forbidden or not?

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms I didn't *ban* built-ins, it's only that I don't encourage them.

Comment: I'd like to see proof that this question *bans* built-ins.

Comment: @py3programmer "so shortest answer (that doesn't use built-ins) wins" is a clear statement that built-ins invalidate answers. Also, for the built-in answers won't be accepted part, accepting answers on code golf challenges at all is discouraged since they don't have a defined ending date.

Comment: It's not invalidating, @RadvylfPrograms. Do you want to discriminate against non-built-in containing answers because they don't have a facility to accomplish this challenge that is built-in and saves bytes all because it doesn't have to be defined?

Comment: @py3programmer You're saying conflicting things. First you're saying it's not invalidating, then you're justifying invalidating them. Why is saying that built-in answers cannot win not invalidating them? And languages which do vs. don't have relevant built-ins doesn't matter since competition is offically purely within the same language.

Comment: Related https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2878/whats-the-day-today-or-other-dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>21</s> <s>20.5</s> <s>16.5</s> 15.5 bytes (31 nibbles)

*Edit: -4 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252621/which-weekday-was-it#comment562554_252644)*

```
%-+/*23@9+_$?-@2 2/%_3~7
```

Saturday is `0` ... Friday is `6`.

Uses [Arnauld's simplified approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252621/which-weekday-was-it#comment562554_252644).

```
%-+/*23@9+_$?-@2 2/%_3~7    
    *23@                     # month times 23
   /    9                    # integer-divided by 9 
  +                          # add this to 
         +_$                 # the year plus the day
 -                           # and subtract
            ?-@2             # if the month is ≤2
                 2           # 2
                             # otherwise
                   %_3       # year modulo 3
                  /   ~      # integer-divided by 2
%                      7     # finally, modulo 7
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

## Excel (ms365), 12 bytes

```
=WEEKDAY(A1)
```

Outputs numbers [1-7] where Sunday == 1;

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

## Excel (ms365), 14 bytes

```
=WEEKDAY(A1,2)
```

Outputs numbers [1-7] where Monday == 1:

[image]

---

## Excel (ms365), 15 bytes

```
=TEXT(A1,"ddd")
```

Outputs lowercase text [mo-su]:

[image]

---

## Excel (ms365), 23 bytes

```
=PROPER(TEXT(A1,"ddd"))
```

Outputs text [Mo-Su] capitalizing the first letter:

[image]

---

**Note:** Excel will recognize the date-strings as actual dates. Therefor having date-strings and date-numbers would have the same effect.

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>31</s> 30 bytes

*Edit: doesn't beat [Robin Ryder's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252639/95126) but at least (currently)  ties it*

```r
function(s)el(as.Date(s):1)%%7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfklhp@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NYMzVHI7FYzyWxJBXIsTLUVFU1B6nRUDIyMDLSNTTQNTBV0vwPAA)

Semi built-in solution.  Thursday is `0`, and then cycles through `1`-`6`.

Comment: [30 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252639/86301) :-p

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>30</s> 27 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to naffetS

```r
function(s)strftime(s,"%A")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfklhp@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NYs7ikKK0kMzdVo1hHSdVRSROkQEPJyMDISNfQQNfAFCgCAA)

3 bytes shorter than the [alternate R solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252630/86301).

The natural solution would be to use `format(as.Date(s), "%A")`, which converts `s`  to the `Date` class then displays only the weekday. Luckily, the `strftime` is a wrapper for this, saving a few bytes.

Comment: Drat!  Well done.

Comment: `function(s)strftime(s,"%A")`

Comment: @naffetS Nice, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>36</s> <s>24</s> <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 19 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
4Ö2‚I3@è³¹²23*9÷Æ7%
```

-12 bytes thanks to *@DominicVanEssen* (and *@Neil*) for reminding me that the challenge years are guaranteed to be 2000-2002
-2 bytes porting [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript (top) answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252703/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!
-1 byte thanks to *@DominicVanEssen* again in *@Arnauld*'s port
-2 bytes taking three loose inputs instead of a triplet

Three loose input-integers in the order `yyyy,MM,dd`; output is an integer where `6` = Sunday, `5` = Monday, ..., `0` = Saturday.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5PA0o0cNszyNHQ6vOLT50M5Dm4yMtSwPbz/cZq76/7@RgYEhlyEQGQEA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVQQmjYoZX/TQ5PM3rUMCvS2OHwiohD6yKNjLUsD28/3Gau@t/F/lHD3KOTDvceXXBoPZCeDcSrjk46tPNRw86je4HE4clABcrFh1coKWgc3q@ppPM/OtrQSMfQUMfIwMAwVifayFLHwAjEMQByDEx0DMxBHCMgB6jGwAIuA@QYwjlGyBxjZI4JMscUmWOGzDGHc2IB).

**Explanation:**

```python
4Ö       # Check if the (implicit) first input-year is divisible by 4
  2‚     # Pair this 0 or 1 with 2
    I    # Push the second input-month
     3@  # Check if it's >=3
       è # Use that to index into the pair
³        # Push the third input-day
 ¹       # Push the first input-year
  ²      # Push the second input-month
   23*   # Multiply the month by 23
      9÷ # Integer-divided by 9
Æ        # Reduce the entire stack by subtracting:
         #  [m%4<1,2][m>=3]-d-y-m*23//9
 7%      # Modulo-7, resulting in 6 to 0 for Sunday to Saturday
```

---

**Original <s>36</s> 24 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer:**

```python
`UD3‹©12*+>₂*T÷®XαD4÷O7%
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9vc2FiaWX//2BVRDPigLnCqTEyKis@4oKCKlTDt8KuWM6xRDTDt083Jf//WzEyLDExLDIwMDFd) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/hFAX40cNOw@tNDTS0rZ71NSkFXJ4@6F1Eec2upgc3u5vrvrfxf5Rw9yjCw6tPzrpcC9Q6eHJQOLo3qOTDu0EiqwC4tlABcrFh1coKWgc3q@ppPM/OtrQSMfQUMfIwMAwVifayFLHwAjEMQByDEx0DMxBHCMgB6jGwAIuA@QYwjlGyBxjZI4JMscUmWOGzDGHc2IB).

**Explanation:**

05AB1E lacks any date builtins (except for the current year/month/day/etc.), so everything is done manually using [Zeller's congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence), taken from [this earlier 05AB1E answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173126/52210):

The formula to do this is:

$${\displaystyle h=\left(q+\left\lfloor{\frac{13(m+1)}{5}}\right\rfloor+K+\left\lfloor{\frac{K}{4}}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor{\frac{J}{4}}\right\rfloor-2J\right){\bmod{7}}}$$

Where for the months March through December:

- \$q\$ is the \$day\$ of the month (`[1, 31]`)
- \$m\$ is the 1-indexed \$month\$ (`[3, 12]`)
- \$K\$ is the year of the century (\$year \bmod 100\$)
- \$J\$ is the 0-indexed century (\$\left\lfloor {\frac {year}{100}}\right\rfloor\$)

And for the months January and February:

- \$q\$ is the \$day\$ of the month (`[1, 31]`)
- \$m\$ is the 1-indexed \$month + 12\$ (`[13, 14]`)
- \$K\$ is the year of the century for the previous year (\$(year - 1) \bmod 100\$)
- \$J\$ is the 0-indexed century for the previous year (\$\left\lfloor {\frac {year-1}{100}}\right\rfloor\$)

Resulting in the day of the week \$h\$, where 0 = Saturday, 1 = Sunday, ..., 6 = Friday.

But, since the challenge states the year is guaranteed to be 2000-2002, we can simplify the formula to this instead:

$${\displaystyle h=\left(q+\left\lfloor{\frac{13(m+1)}{5}}\right\rfloor+K+\left\lfloor{\frac{K}{4}}\right\rfloor\right){\bmod{7}}}$$

Resulting in the day of the week \$h\$, where 0 = Friday, 1 = Saturday, ..., 6 = Thursday.

As for the actual program:

```python
`           # Push the day, month, and year of the (implicit) input-triplet to the stack
 U          # Pop and save the year in variable `X`
  D         # Duplicate the month
   3‹       # Check if the month is below 3 (Jan. / Feb.),
            # resulting in 1 or 0 for truthy/falsey respectively
     ©      # Store this in variable `®` (without popping)
      12*   # Multiply it by 12 (either 0 or 12)
         +  # And add it to the month
            # This first part was to make Jan. / Feb. 13 and 14

>           # Month + 1
 ₂*         # Multiplied by 26
   T÷       # Integer-divided by 10
®           # Push month<3 from variable `®` again
 Xα         # Take the absolute difference with the year
D4÷         # mYear, integer-divided by 4
O           # Sum all values on the stack together
 7%         # And then take modulo-7 to complete the formula,
            # resulting in 0 to 6 for Friday to Thursday
            # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: Impressive... I hadn't thought of this when writing a Python program to determine the first day of year 1 AD. It would have come in handy,

Comment: As I understand it, you're only required to support dates in 2000-2002, which might let you simplify the code a bit.

Comment: Presumably this would be only [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/hFAX40cNOw@tNDTS0rZ71NSkFXJ4@6F1Eec2upgc3u5vrvrfxf5Rw9yjkw73ApUdngwkju49OunQTqDIKiCefXTBofVABcrFh1coKWgc3q@ppPM/OtrQSMfQUMfIwMAwVifayFLHwAjEMQByDEx0DMxBHCMgB6jGwAIiEwsA) if all the parts that aren't needed for 2000-2002 are removed...?  (obviously the conversion to day names in the link is now wrong)

Comment: In the new 22-byte version, if you use integer-divide-by-9, then I don't think you need the bitwise-negate step ([I think](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/Q8sSTA5PM3rUMKvY2OHwisqEYiNjLcvD2w@3mav@d7F/1DD36KTDvY8adh6eDCSO7j066dBOoMgqIJ59dMGh9UAFysWHVygpaBzer6mk8z862tBIx9BQx8jAwDBWJ9rIUsfACMQxAHIMTHQMzEEcIyAHqMbAAi4D5BjCOUbIHGNkjgkyxxSZY4bMMYdzYgE)...): you'll just map ```6..0``` to consecutive days instead of ```0..6```, which is fine.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I was just about to write a similar comment. The only reason why I used a bitwise-NOT in my JS version is that it was shorter than a floor. But it would be easier to port [this version](https://tio.run/##TZA/TsMwFMb3nuJbUGySBidFVKWELogBqXTIxGjFThrkxFViQBHiBkgsjHAPztMLcITwkgFFsq333u97//won2WbNeXBzWurdJ8nPesCVAEUR3INpuCjo7uVbh/mxtqGxQucosIZVhxzsApXWGBDqhOckx3hEjE4J3fZ56QvkSBaoxyYWC3J8n2O1xmgpNMEa/2CGzJZLIQIQKfka8IdsUESFtrdPhnzoGXDRlJNyNbWbs84zRgNSE3QWHRMaHRL8fx/t/WMgpmtW2t0aGzBxhRn79LdPeNha8pMMxFEggdDLpHUNWVdEDtIlTrZOBYTY0NhHxfjtkimrTuaaQPv9@fj@PVJr0f/4h2/3z1q/tb/AQ) instead.

Comment: (Not that it really matters, but you'll still get the days in increasing order by doing it that way.)

Comment: @Arnauld - That version comes-out particularly short [in Nibbles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252805/95126): thank you!

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks for the -1. And I was able to save another 2 by taking loose inputs instead of a triplet.

Comment: @Arnauld The current approach is actually shorter, since I can do 'reduce-by-subtraction' on the stack in a single byte. :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 13 bytes

```
func[d][d/10]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy8WVZvU/rTQvOTolNjpF39Ag9n9aflFqYnKGQkpiSapCNJcCEBgZGBjqGgKREYxroGtgpGtkCeMa6RqY6xqYIMlaANVzxUYXFGXmlSikgQ2L5fwPAA)

Returns `1` to `7`, Monday is 1

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 46 bytes

```
func[d][take/part system/locale/days/(d/10) 2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYw7CsMwEETr6BRbJoXQagnkcwy3QsWiXZEQxzaSUvj0igkYMkzzeMMUlT6ohGhMvvf8mVKQGBq/1C1cGtS1Nn27cU48qhNeqzuK83gCij3PRTk9QLgpBANbCNFbv5V2RItk6bYjWbxYPP/Z67Y3MSzlOTXIv7N46F8)

Returns `Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su`

[Red](http://www.red-lang.org)'s `date!` datatype has `weekday` accessor that is also aliased by index 10. So for a date `d` we can write `d/weekday` or shorter `d/10`

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes

This is an attempt at solving the challenge without a built-in, using a formula optimized for 2000-2002.

Expects `(year, month, day)`. Returns \$0\$ for Sunday, \$1\$ for Monday, ..., \$6\$ for Saturday.

```javascript
(y,m,d)=>~((m<3?y%4<1:2)-d-y-23*m/9)%7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4xTsQwEEV7TjHNKjZxgpNFWu1uwjaIAgkoUlFasROM4njlGFCE4ARINJRwD86zF9gjhEloIo1Go//mz59H8Sy60um9j1or1VDlA@mZYZLmF@@EmGy56xfnWbJJaSSjPkqXp@ZsTRerobKOaMgh2YKGDBK@XuEUhhReTwCk8Aphq17gEkeScs4ZYGm6RdwjG1fiWvmrp6a5V8KRiZgZubGtfyAUQgwZb87QdHQyONWhXuHXYBhI1FAsbdvZRsWNrclk8fa6uLslNO4aXSrCWcIpG71ICu90WyPbC1l44TxJ/xnk88AeP9lBcPz9PHx/YQ9gA8Hh5yPAyLfhDw)

#### Commented

This is based on the following C code by Michael Keith and Tom Craver:

```c
(d+=m<3?y--:y-2,23*m/9+d+4+y/4-y/100+y/400)%7
```

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week#Keith)

```javascript
(y, m, d) =>    // y = year, m = month, d = day
~(              // take the ones' complement of:
  (             //   conditional offset:
    m < 3 ?     //     if this is January or February:
      y % 4 < 1 //       use 1 if this is 2000
                //       (which is a leap year)
                //       or 0 otherwise
    :           //     else:
      2         //       use 2
  )             //
  - d           //   subtract the non-conditional offset:
  - y           //     d + y + 23 * m / 9
  - 23 * m / 9  //
) % 7           // apply modulo 7
```

Comment: +1 for trying out without Built-ins, but not gonna be accepted because the shorter solution without built-ins is -2 bytes in 05AB1E

Comment: @py3programmer The 05AB1E answer would be shorter if it was also optimized for 2000-2002. There's no way JS can compete with a golfing language. :-)

Comment: Eich's fault, not mine.

Comment: @Arnauld It's optimized for 2000-2002 now. ;) But I have the feeling it might be shorter porting your top answer. 

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
lambda*t:date(*t).weekday()
from datetime import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUavEKiWxJFVDq0RTrzw1NTslsVJDkyutKD9XASRekpmbqpCZW5BfVKL1v6AoM69EI03DyMDAUMcQiIw0NbmQBA10jHQsUYWMdMx1TNBVWQA1a2r@BwA)

Represents mon-sun as 0-6

Comment: Is that 0–6 or 1–7?

Comment: @Adám [0,7) - but in all fairness I just made a typo

Comment: Not sure if this is valid since it uses builtins

Comment: It's valid, but it won't be considered for being accepted.

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <sup><s>14</s></sup> 13 bytes

```bash
date -d$1 +%u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7vaoMwEP/uUxxZBhEJxNCxFpdt0O0ptB9cctKwocWkIIjP7k7bdVtICL@/dx91OM7NubXRdy00IoVxdnVEkI7nkN2f5ylxaL/qnqgaIoZoBNNK5TKnqxksQEmlpd5dgJbqUarNTdmSk6V/W3A4oY3ojMhBwwYe/qn2iPYTexpTDe@6GnZ7ekvdFb5Vw3ZPhU3XgxDgjSrAPzE@3v30lq@HiRWQZT5NC9clQCcacizrl9yTunK4cLfQLx8MFw0wHmnKmqUYwcDAGPrx4jr1vo2rDeQz8AB8vK5e8pfDVLUscV2L8zc)

*Saved a byte thanks to [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)!!!*

Inputs the date as `YYYY-MM-DD` and returns \$1\$ for Monday, \$2\$ for Tuesday, up to \$7\$ for Sunday.

Comment: You can remove the space between `-d` and `$1`.

Comment: @Steffan Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 7 bytes

```
DayName
```

### Mathematica (without `DayName`), <s>49</s> <s>42</s> 38 bytes

```
First@DateDifference[{1,1,1},#]~Mod~7&
```

[View it on Wolfram Cloud!](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/2f7e7dd4-9d31-4d34-92d6-2f20e1b620be)

Takes dates in `MM/DD/YYYY` format (will complain if the date happens to be parsable as `DD/MM/YYYY`, but it still outputs the correct answer). `DayName` returns the full name of the weekday. The other answer returns 0 for Monday, 1 for Tuesday, up to 6 for Sunday.

The non-`DayName` answer can probably still be golfed a decent amount, I'm pretty new to Mathematica.

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, 10 bytes

```
=MOD(A1,7)
```

Returns `0W/01/1900` where `W` is `0`–`6` for Saturday–Friday.
[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: @thejonymyster Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: `W` is Saturday-Friday (except for before 1900-03-01 when it is Sunday-Saturday as Excel has a bug and thinks 1900-02-29 was a leap day).

Comment: @MT0 Not sure what you're trying to say here, but yes, you're right. However, since mod-7 always gives a number between 0 and 6, corresponding to a date between 1899-12-31 (a.k.a 1900-01-00) and 1900-01-06, it'll never happen that `W` corresponds to Saturday–Friday.

Comment: Using Saturday's date `=MOD(DATE(2022,10,8), 7)` outputs `00/01/1900` so the initial `00` corresponds to Saturday (and not Sunday, like the answer states).

Comment: @MT0 Oh, now I get it. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: The aside in my initial comment relates to a bug in Excel where it thinks that 1900 was a leap year (it wasn't) and that 1900-02-29 was a valid date (it wasn't). This means that `=MOD(DATE(1900,1,6), 7)` (which is the first Saturday in 1900) will not output `00/01/1900` instead you get `06/01/1900` and the start of the week shifts by one day due to the erroneous leap day. If you are only interested in dates after `1900-03-01` then you can ignore this bug.

Comment: @MT0 Right, and since OP only requires that "it can calculate for years between 2000 and 2002", that bug doesn't matter. The phantom 29th Feb 1900 isn't a bug but a feature for compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3. And Lotus 1-2-3 was intentionally implemented using a simplified leap year calculation for code golf purposes.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>16</s> 6 bytes

Takes datetime object as input, [per OP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252621/which-weekday-was-it/252685#comment562259_252621).

Takes date as `YYYY-MM-DD` and returns 0–6 for Thursday–Wednesday.

```js
d=>d%7
```

#### Old solution with string input

```javascript
s=>new Date(s)%7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1i4vtVzBJbEkVaNYU9X8f3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RlqCkYGBoa4hEBklaHJhSBnoGhjpGllikzLSNTDXNTDBocsCaGaC5n8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 11 bytes

```
day-of-week
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBDoIwEAXQfU/xPQCmuCJo3Bo3bAwHmLSfxLQWHMaYnr68t0iwVdv8ek6PEUEySxRFohZmbEqzuum7GHZ@fyyBO67OXbz38AP6HrcoxjtwQsUH0bUotVuX7k@mdm4H)

Takes input as a `timestamp`. Outputs an integer `0-6` signifying `Sunday-Saturday`.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 7 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function taking date as `YYYY MM DD`.

```
7|1⎕DT⊂
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=M68xfNQ31SXkUVcTAA&f=e9Q39VHbhDQFIwMDQwVDIDLieoQQMlAwMFIwskQWMlIwMFcwMEFTZQHUCwA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

`⊂` enclose to make a scalar date

`1⎕DT` convert to Dyalog Day Number (days since 1899-12-31)

`7|` remainder when divided by 7 (gives 0–6 for Sunday–Saturday)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

Takes input as an array like `[Y,M,D]` and returns a number from `0` (Sunday) to `6` (Saturday).

-1 byte thanks to [Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92901/dingus)

```ruby
->d{Time.gm(*d).wday}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpclW0km5RSmJJqlLsojTbpaUlaboWW3XtUqpDMnNT9dJzNbRSNPXKUxIrayFyN-MLFNKio40MDAx1FAxB2Cg2VkFZwTefCyZhoKNgBESWYPGQUrg4UNBcR8EEIpyBrNwCZBRY3K0IYs2CBRAaAA)

Comment: `Time.gm` saves a byte over `Date.new` (and doesn't need `-rdate`).

Comment: @Dingus Nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 16 bytes

```powershell
%{date $_|% D*k}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvbmRgYKhrCERG6joKIJ6BroGRrpEllGeka2Cua2CCkLMAKlZXqPmvWp2SWJKqoBJfo6rgopVd@/8/AA)

Input comes from the pipeline.
Straightforward:

```powershell
%{date $_|% D*k}
%{             }  # % is an alias for ForEach-Object; the loop variable in the ScriptBlock "{}" is $_
  date $_         # pass the string as input to Get-Date, which will return a DateTime object
         |% D*k   # pipe the DateTime object to ForEach-Object, this time not with a ScriptBlock, but instead calls the member DayOfWeek
                  # Output is implicit
```

**Disclaimer:** This drops the `Get-` from `Get-Date`; if PS finds no other command with that name, it will try to add `Get-` and find the cmdlet `Get-Date`; don't use this in regular scripts, as the search for the command will slow it down.

Answer (score 2):

### JS, <s>23</s> 13 bytes

Passed as string

```
s=>new Date(s).getDay()
```

Passed as object, per OP

```
d=>d.getDay()
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
8XO
```

Input format is `YYYY/MM/DD`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yLC//9/dSMDA0N9QyAyUgcA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8N8iwv@/S8h/dSMDA0N9QyAyUucCcQz0DYz0jSwhHCN9A3N9AxO4jAVQpToA).

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```julia
using Dates;!d=Dates.dayofweek(Date(d))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v7Q4My9dwSWxJLXYWjHFFszQS0mszE8rT03N1gDxNVI0Nf/nJhZoKOpEKxkZGBjqGgKRkZKOAohnoGtgpGtkCeUZ6RqY6xqYIOQsgIqVYjUVauwUCooy80r@AwA)

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)!*

Returns 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, up to 7 for Sunday.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice answer. You can save a couple bytes by defining `f` as a unary operator instead: `using Dates;!d=Dates.dayofweek(Date(d))`

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>29</s> 21 bytes

```
4Ḋ2"?3≥i???23*9ḭWƒ-7%
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI04biKMlwiPzPiiaVpPz8/MjMqOeG4rVfGki03JSIsIiIsIjIwMDFcbjExXG4xMiJd)

Port of 05AB1E.

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>96</s> 85 bytes

```go
import."time"
func f(d string)int{e,_:=Parse("02/01/2006",d);return int(e.Weekday())}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY1LCsIwEED3PUXIKoHapEG0Kt6hG3EpoU1KqElLmi6keBI3RfAS3sTbmH4Q6Wpg3sx7j2dR9e-aZyUvBNBcmUDpurIORFBqB1-tk6vkc5qWEXRKCxjI1mRAohw0zipTYGVcJ8LL_phy2wgEKSM0JozSDQxzfLDCtdYAf4VEdBaizPkNYXyf5c2oG9oIgy5IvdJdDZIIxozEoyeGGP8DtiO-4QFdALomdDsAtgDeQ5Pfx5zu-2l-AQ)

Hoo ray for verbose builtins!

- -11 bytes for returning an `int` (@Steffan)

Comment: You don't need the `[:2]` - any consistent 7 values are valid.

Comment: It's 85 bytes to return an int: `func f(d string)int{e,_:=Parse("02/01/2006",d);return int(e.Weekday())}`

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 47 bytes

```
import times,sugar
x=>x.parse"ddMMyyyy".weekday
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc4xC8MgEIbhPb/icDJQwimFtkI6dc3cWaJJpRhFLTW/3kome9Px8A3vZmwx1ruQIBmrY@eDmyHSRcDx0SwgpmC2tRfw1Pr9kHsPYweg55eDBQjjjHFERhrjN@TVsDU846Uab40xvB67v4ZT/KwydJHm8Z4HL0PURKlp2uuR4VsjVI0o5Qc)

It takes the date in the format `ddMMyyyy` and prints the full name of the weekday.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 33 bytes

```php
<?=date('l',strtotime($argv[1]));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42JbEkVUM9R12nuKSoJL8kMzdVQyWxKL0s2jBWU9P6////RgZGRrqGBroGZgA)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in PHP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/tips-for-golfing-in-php) page for ways you can golf your program.

Comment: If you don't mind using older versions of PHP (7.1 and older), you can save 2 bytes by removing the single quotes: `<?=date(l,strtotime($argv[1]));`. If you use the option `-R`, you can use the `$argn` variable instead of `$argv[1]` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php). The final code would look like: `<?=date(l,strtotime($argn));` - 5 bytes saved in total.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com) REPL, 0 bytes

Takes date as `7|1⎕DT⊂YYYY MM DD` and gives 0–6 for Sunday–Saturday

[Try it on TryAPL!](https://tryapl.org/?clear&q=7%7C1%E2%8E%95DT%E2%8A%822001%2011%2012&run)

This abuses [OP ruling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252621/which-weekday-was-it/252685#comment562260_252621) that a valid input format can contain the code that solves the problem. For an explanation, see [my other APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252684/43319).

Answer (score 0):

## jq, 17 characters

```
strptime("%F")[6]
```

Input: YYYY-MM-DD
Output: 0 = Sunday .. 6 = Saturday

Sample run:

```
bash-5.1$ jq -R 'strptime("%F")[6]' <<< '2012-05-04'   # manatwork joined CGCC
5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/7@4pKigJDM3VUNJ1U1JM9os9v9/IwMDQ11DIDL6lw@Uy88r/q@rW5RYrpuZV1BaAgA) / [Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##lY9NS8NAEIbP3V8xrmk3OSxsltYPTEAPFjyIULzFUGKyJdGaxN0NCNXfns6mpdWDh8IyMzz7zsw7r5kp@0Ll60wr4HdglbHLPDMq9skoYVKIkIf4JEvjEM7hsdljwYXk8hqxRPzc7bHk4pKLKeKpw@VRfYVzEM8QzzUJCGl1VdsVsG8Y83BmYMjiT5YYX2oG7KFuO4t5oUy3dsX9V6tyqwosn94ZIatGQ@VEGIF6m7PDIclt@kNvoEDjeuiOqefD2yfwBbDeWN3a6kP5dDynQXKR9gyiKMIRwzQKASVkdILVQyP1dutctTm62X2jJXA2kuSXLo7/k6YpTCag8rIZznWmiqZW/RY)

Answer (score 0):

## Rust + chrono, <s>58</s> 21 bytes

```rust
chrono::Date::weekday
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9c37c5abb57131f38aba75997ac8a594)

An expression that can be coerced to a `fn(&Date<Utc>)->Weekday`. It takes a Date object and returns Weekday, an enum with 7 possible values.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 13 bytes

```java
d->d.getDay()
```

A `Function<java.util.Date, Integer>`. Returns 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, ..., 6 for Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Input as a string in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` (or any valid JavaScript date string), output as a 3 letter abbreviation.

```
3îÐU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=M%2b7QVQ&input=IjIwMDEtMTEtMTIi)

```
3îÐU     :Implicit input of string U
3î       :Slice to length 3
  ÐU     :Construct date object from U
```

**Note:** This is locale/browser dependent. For the included test case, for example, the date object is expected to return `Mon Nov 12 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `t`, 22 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
4Ḋ2,$3®i⁶°¹23×9÷KrƲ-7%
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UolS7IKlpSVpuhY3FUwe7ugy0lExPrQu81HjtkMbDu00Mj483fLwdu-iY5t0zVWXFCclF0NVL1hlZGBgyGUIREYQEQA)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
                        # implicit input
4Ḋ                      # divisible by 4
  2,                    # pair with 2
    $                   # next input
     3®                 # greater than or equal to 3
       i                # indexing
        ⁶               # third input
         °              # first input
          ¹             # second input
           23×          # multiply by 23
              9÷        # floor divide by 9
                Kr      # push the stack
                  Ʋ     # cumulative reduce by:
                   -    #  subtraction
                    7%  # modulo 7
                        # implicit output of tail
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 69 bytes

```python
lambda y,m,d:((d+((y+y//4)+(0x562ad0e6c0>>m*3&7)))-(m<3)*(y%4<1)+6)%7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcJBCoMwFAXAq7ixvGdSjEYjFPUkbtKm0oJRKS76Tx8dZpfjs602zcOUFh@fwWeiow4PIChAlJRlQwXzb13tg3m7lxnHWNhbR/KO2FsWkLzpKyrHvEv777semFE5ndVXQ6YT)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), with java packages, 70 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5NC4JAFEX38yseQaBQgwkRCAaBBULRoq9FRLzyKWM6yvgKIvrtNhW0aXnuuRduc8YCW1XWlWHI8YaSVUlyXtk8Qibxp9LKlMjyLdeWZx9kMkJUp5zODAtUGh4CIKEUSgsOmqwJYGIM3vcrNkpnBzeAjVYM4acJUNuUC@0kTsf3fL8/8PresOO6Vj6FuGEBSfCdhuNY2137uyhrNA05xx78fZLxanmMJuupKzPiCO/LdEd0ecMWiyt1R@2zfQE)

```scala
LocalDate.parse(_, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE).getDayOfWeek.getValue%7
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVBdS8NAEHzPr1gKwhXao0SkUKhQiEJA6UOrgiJlTTYxNbkLd9tKKPnt8fKBInm5Y3Z2Z2fHRphj02RFqQ3DEc8oOStIXh60YwJkmsGrVhTGtTdqSrQpkGXbtXf4voNMxvP0x5EihkfMFFw8gJgSKBwQaFK7go0xWL3t2GQqfZ@u4EllDOuuE6B0Vc6ViLESE3/hX88XN3N/OZlOxzRr9/VM7Q17WsLt6NWdeKj@tM@YO57JFawzxNHnQABEaAkGQVjfwm8AUulv0WcgbWWZioASPOUsBkfD7OH/VInGkrAzGMUjw932EGz2d/143b2tK5kSB1htkxeirxY8Y34iuIJld1/tNc0P)

```scala
import java.time.{LocalDate, ZoneId}
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(day("2023-05-27"))
    println(day("today"))
  }

  def day(s: String): Int = {
    val date = s match {
      case "today" => LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
      case _ => LocalDate.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)
    }
    date.getDayOfWeek.getValue % 7
  }
}
```